# Kubuntu package upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, kde, plasma-5

I'm currently running 18.04.2 LTS (Kubuntu). I've received an upgrade notification for the following packages:

```
libegl-mesa0/bionic-updates 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.1]
libegl1-mesa/bionic-updates 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.1]
libgbm1/bionic-updates 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.1]
libgl1-mesa-dri/bionic-updates 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.1]
libgl1-mesa-glx/bionic-updates 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.1]
libglapi-mesa/bionic-updates 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.1]
libglx-mesa0/bionic-updates 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.1]
libwayland-egl1-mesa/bionic-updates 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.1]
libxatracker2/bionic-updates 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.1]
mesa-va-drivers/bionic-updates 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.1]
mesa-vdpau-drivers/bionic-updates 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.1]
```

I wasn't planning on upgrading from LTS until the next LTS. Will I have any issues with my system if I do/don't do these upgrades?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you allow the upgrades you cited, you will remain on Kubuntu 18.04 LTS. The version numbers of the packages are admittedly confusing. While I can't explain the version numbers satisfactorily, part of the reason is that our Kubuntu desktop has software from three different "entities", each with their own numbering:

KDE Applications
Plasma
KDE Frameworks

See [this](https://kde.org/download/) for more.

On Kubuntu 18.04 LTS, we currently have

- Plasma at 5.12.8
- KDE Frameworks at 5.44.0 and
- KDE Applications at 17.12.3

Then there are also packages provided by Ubuntu core as well which have their own version numbers.

For example on my Kubuntu 18.04 LTS:

- Konsole is version 17.12.3
- Dolphin is version 17.12.3
- Kate is version 17.12.3

but

- libglu1-mesa is version 9.0.0-2
- mesa-utils is version 8.4.0-1
- etc

And here's an extract from my */var/log/apt/history.log* formatted by me to be more presentable:

```
Start-Date: 2019-07-04  09:36:00  
Commandline: apt full-upgrade  
Requested-By: dkb (1000)  
Install: libllvm8:amd64 (1:8-3~ubuntu18.04.1, automatic)  
Upgrade: libdrm-nouveau2:amd64 (2.4.95-1~18.04.1, 2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1),  
libegl-mesa0:amd64 (18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2, 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.1),
libglapi-mesa:amd64 (18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2, 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.1), 
libxatracker2:amd64 (18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2, 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.1), 
libegl1-mesa:amd64 (18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2, 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.1), 
libgbm1:amd64 (18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2, 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.1), 
libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 (2.4.95-1~18.04.1, 2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64 (18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2, 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.1), 
libdrm2:amd64 (2.4.95-1~18.04.1, 2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2, 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.1), 
libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2, 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.1), 
libdrm-intel1:amd64 (2.4.95-1~18.04.1, 2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
libdrm-radeon1:amd64 (2.4.95-1~18.04.1, 2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1), 
mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2, 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.1), 
linux-firmware:amd64 (1.173.6, 1.173.8), 
mesa-va-drivers:amd64 (18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2, 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.1), 
libglx-mesa0:amd64 (18.2.8-0ubuntu0~18.04.2, 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.1), 
libdrm-common:amd64 (2.4.95-1~18.04.1, 2.4.97-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)  
End-Date: 2019-07-04  09:37:42
```

In short, there's no ill-effect in accepting the updates. And since the next LTS won't be due till April 2020, that shouldn't be a concern.

If you're sure you want to remain on the LTS track, make sure you have this:

[image: Software Settings]

---

In case you ever need to know more about a package, you can run `apt show libgbm1`, for example, to know more about *libgbm1*. Some selected output from there:

> Version: 19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.2

> Origin: Ubuntu

> Maintainer: Ubuntu X-SWAT

> Task: ubuntu-desktop, kubuntu-desktop, xubuntu-core, xubuntu-desktop, core-share, lubuntu-gtk-core, lubuntu-desktop-share, lubuntu-core, lubuntu-qt-core, ubuntustudio-desktop-core, ubuntustudio-desktop, ubuntukylin-desktop, ubuntu-mate-core, ubuntu-mate-desktop, ubuntu-budgie-desktop

> Supported: 5y

> Description: generic buffer management API -- runtime

Note the lines starting with *Origin* and *Tasks*. The first mentions *Ubuntu*, indicating that Canonical supports this package. The second line, based on the number of desktop varieties listed there, indicates that this package is used by all those flavors.